# Why do laptop screens flicker during video mode changes?

Tags: display, lcd, firmware, display-settings

Changing the display mode (resolution and/or refresh rate) causes the screen to flicker or go dark for a few seconds before the image stabilizes. At least this happens on all laptops and desktops I've used. Why ?

As [explained here](https://superuser.com/questions/484268/why-does-changing-lcd-screen-resolution-windows-7-take-several-seconds), when using a complex operating system, part of the delay is due to the display software. However **I'm not interested in the "software" delay due to heavy user-interfaces and window management, but only in the "hardware" delay** which causes flickering, backlight blinks, etc.

This flickering and delay happens between the firmware greet (bios/efi) and the first installed software (OS splash or bootloader), and the same happens when changing resolution from within all the windows and linux versions I've tried, so it obviously has nothing to do with higher level software such as graphical shells or windows managers.

I see multiple (hypothetical!) causes:

- **Physical delay ?**, like for old CRT display there was a low noise probably indicating the power electronics driving the electron beam was reset. Maybe on LCD the backlight power is reset, which causes flickering and delay, but why does it have to be reset?
- **Very slow protocol ?** Brian suggested that the resolution change protocol between the GPU and the display panel is slow. Experience shows that the flickering is not as long on newer laptop, which points in this direction. What I don't get is this : listing available resolutions and sending the desired one should take a few (kilo) bytes and video signals transit @Gbps speeds and a few ms latencies, so how come it takes around a second to negotiate a resolution change ?
- **Display embedded electronics reconfiguration** : kreemoweet states on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/745874/do-you-have-any-ressources-on-protocols-involved-in-video-mode-changing?noredirect=1#comment961921_745874) question that there is no protocol involved but each frame caries its resolution. When a frame has a different resolution than the last, the on-board electronics driving the display needs to be reconfigured: registers and buffers are reallocated, etc. The details are blurry but the electronics can efficiently process the video frames once configured, but takes a (relatively) long time to get configured.
- **Maybe some other reason ?**

Comment: @techie007: thanks, it's close but I'm not interested in the software side but only the hardware/firmware : the delay happens even during the bios/os transition so it's not related to high level software issues

Comment: @Mokubail could you kindly explain why you marked this as duplicate? In case your decision was only based on the title I changed it. I also  (tried to) clarify the question. Could you please reconsider?

Answer (score 1):

Negotiation of the resolution and refresh rate between the monitor and the computer is reliant on the connection. Using an older analog VGA connection is much slower than using newer digital standards. The two quickest ways to get rid of delays when changing desktop/game resolution:

1. Have the graphics card do any required scaling to the monitor's
   native resolution.
2. Use a newer digital connection like DVI that negotiates changes faster.

Comment: Thanks! How does LVDS (for laptops) compare to dvi? More importantly, both have high speeds and low latencies: how come the negociation is so long since it probably transfers less bytes than a full frame? Can you point me to the protocol involved?